# Why does "break" behave like it does in the following piece of code?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, break

```
count = 1
i = 3
while count != 1000:
     for k in range(2,i):
          if i%k == 0:       
              break
     else:
          print(i)
          count += 1
     i += 2
```

In this piece of python code, if `break` is executed the program will jump over to adding `i += 2`, is it not supposed to execute `else` first?

Given that `else` is not indented to the same level of `if` and thus does not make part of the `for` loop.

Comment: ``else`` *is* part of the ``for`` loop - it is at the same level of indentation as ``for k in ...``. That's why it does not execute when the code ``break``s the ``for`` loop. When would you assume the ``else`` clause to execute?

Comment: The `else` corresponds to the for-loop and gets only executed if you didn't `break` out of the loop.

Comment: You have it backwards; the `else` executes if the loop *isn't* terminated by `break`.

Comment: Whenever I attach an `else` to a `for` or `while` loop, I put a comment after: `else:  # no break` just to avoid this sort of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

From python docs - https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

> The break statement, like in C, breaks out of the innermost enclosing for or while loop.

> Loop statements may have an else clause; it is executed when the loop terminates through exhaustion of the iterable (with for) or when the condition becomes false (with while), but not when the loop is terminated by a break statement.

Hence, the `break` statement skips the `else` clause, and the next statement to execute is `i += 2`

Answer (score 0):

The `break` is for when the program found the `k` it wanted.
If it doesn't break, `k` will get larger due to the iteration.
Let's say at iteration 10, `i` / `k` leaves no remainder, we want *that*
specific `k`. 
If a for loop ends with a `break`, 
the `else` statement gets ignored,
otherwise, the `else` statement gets launched.